# こちらのエラーコードの意味を教えてください。

Tags: php, wordpress

プログラムのことはほぼ分からない者です。
現在、WooCommerceのショップページのindexページでエラーが出ており困っています。
webコンソールで表示されていたエラーコードをどなたかご解読いただけませんでしょうか。

```
Note: MonsterInsights does not track you as a logged-in site administrator to prevent site owners from accidentally skewing their own Google Analytics data.
If you are testing Google Analytics code, please do so either logged out or in the private browsing/incognito mode of your web browser.
?v=2.0:6 WebSocket connection to 'wss://public-api.wordpress.com/pinghub/wpcom/me/newest-note-data' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403
g @ ?v=2.0:6
T @ ?v=2.0:6
j @ ?v=2.0:6
?v=2.0:6 WebSocket connection to 'wss://public-api.wordpress.com/pinghub/wpcom/me/newest-note-data' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out
g @ ?v=2.0:6
T @ ?v=2.0:6
j @ ?v=2.0:6
pixel.wp.com/boom.gif?v=0.9&u=https://public-api.wordpress.com/pinghub&json={%22beacons%22:[%22pinghub.conn_err.unknown:30710|ms%22]}:1 GET https://pixel.wp.com/boom.gif?v=0.9&u=https://public-api.wordpress.com/pinghub&json={%22beacons%22:[%22pinghub.conn_err.unknown:30710|ms%22]} net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
Image (async)
c @ ?v=2.0:6
e.onerror @ ?v=2.0:6
error (async)
g @ ?v=2.0:6
T @ ?v=2.0:6
j @ ?v=2.0:6
?v=2.0:6 WebSocket connection to 'wss://public-api.wordpress.com/pinghub/wpcom/me/newest-note-data' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
g @ ?v=2.0:6
T @ ?v=2.0:6
j @ ?v=2.0:6
pixel.wp.com/boom.gif?v=0.9&u=https://public-api.wordpress.com/pinghub&json={%22beacons%22:[%22pinghub.conn_close_code.1006.unknown:30711|ms%22]}:1 GET https://pixel.wp.com/boom.gif?v=0.9&u=https://public-api.wordpress.com/pinghub&json={%22beacons%22:[%22pinghub.conn_close_code.1006.unknown:30711|ms%22]} net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
Image (async)
c @ ?v=2.0:6
e.onclose @ ?v=2.0:6
pixel.wp.com/boom.gif?v=0.9&u=https://public-api.wordpress.com/pinghub&json={%22beacons%22:[%22pinghub.conn_err.unknown:23818|ms%22]}:1 GET https://pixel.wp.com/boom.gif?v=0.9&u=https://public-api.wordpress.com/pinghub&json={%22beacons%22:[%22pinghub.conn_err.unknown:23818|ms%22]} net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
Image (async)
c @ ?v=2.0:6
e.onerror @ ?v=2.0:6
error (async)
g @ ?v=2.0:6
T @ ?v=2.0:6
j @ ?v=2.0:6
pixel.wp.com/boom.gif?v=0.9&u=https://public-api.wordpress.com/pinghub&json={%22beacons%22:[%22pinghub.conn_close_code.1006.unknown:23819|ms%22]}:1 GET https://pixel.wp.com/boom.gif?v=0.9&u=https://public-api.wordpress.com/pinghub&json={%22beacons%22:[%22pinghub.conn_close_code.1006.unknown:23819|ms%22]} net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
Image (async)
c @ ?v=2.0:6
e.onclose @ ?v=2.0:6
3?v=2.0:6 WebSocket connection to 'wss://public-api.wordpress.com/pinghub/wpcom/me/newest-note-data' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403
g @ ?v=2.0:6
T @ ?v=2.0:6
j @ ?v=2.0:6
```

Answer (score 1):

#### 困っていること対策(案)

ご質問のサイトの管理者であれば、ログインした状態で以下のいずれかの操作でエラーが解消されるかお試しください。

- wordpress.comに[ログインする](https://wordpress.com/ja/forums/topic/wordpress-com%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AB%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%81%A7%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/)
- MonsterInsightの通知機能を無効化する cf:[Jetpackで無効化する操作](https://webrandum.net/jetpack-error-during-websocket-handshake/)

ご質問のサイトはwordpressにMonsterInsightというアクセス解析ツールを導入しているようですが、あらかじめwordpress.comにログインしておかないと通知の処理でpublic-api.wordpress.comドメインへの接続が拒否される模様です。[参考にしたサイト](http://blog1.dd-company.com/failed-error-during-websocket-handshake-unexpected-response-code-403/)

#### エラーコードの意味

> Note: MonsterInsights does not track you as a logged-in site administrator to prevent site owners from accidentally skewing their own Google Analytics data.
> If you are testing Google Analytics code, please do so either logged out or in the private browsing/incognito mode of your web browser.
> ?v=2.0:6 WebSocket connection to 'wss://public-api.wordpress.com/pinghub/wpcom/me/newest-note-data' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403

※下記は一部抜粋による超訳ですのでご注意ください

ノート: (あなたのwordpressサイトに)管理者ログインしてるときはGoogle Analyticsへの影響を防ぐため解析しません。
Google Analyticsもテストしたい時はログアウトするかブラウザのシークレットタブなどを使ってください。
ウェブソケットで'wss://public-api.wordpress.com/...'につなげません。接続しようとしても403エラーで拒否されました。

なお公式サイトのドキュメントには、ログインしていても解析させたい場合の設定が載っています。
https://www.monsterinsights.com/docs/tracking-disabled-administrators-editors/

Comment: ご丁寧にご回答いただきありがとうございました。
私は管理者ではないので、Wordpress.comへのログインはできませんでした。
一度、クライアントに情報を聞いてみます。

この件でもう一つ質問なのですが、
上記のエラーによりWooCommerceのショップページ（index:トップ画面）に
商品一覧が表示されないことはありえますか？

今、この表示されない問題で困っています。
恐れ入りますが、お分かりでしたらご教授くださいませ。

Comment: 率直に申し上げますと、このプラグインを使用したことがないのでエラーによる影響は存じ上げません。構築手順や設定の問題が疑われますので、クライアントにバグ票を出すか、エラーや症状をまとめて別途ご質問いただくのがよろしいかと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ヒントをいただけただけでも助かりました。もしかしたら見当違いの場所を探っているかもしれないので、再度、エラー状況を見直してみます。